# Error found when downloading Apache Solr

Tags: apache-spark, solr, web-crawler

I'm trying to use Sparkler: Crawler on Apache Spark. I begin with requirements in this link: https://github.com/uscdataScience/sparkler/wiki/sparkler-0.1#requirements
The first step was to download Apache Solr. So, when I use this command:

```
cp -rv ${SPARKLER_GIT_SOURCE_PATH}/conf/solr/crawldb server/solr/configsets/
```

It shows this error:
   `cp: cannot stat ‘/conf/solr/crawldb’: No such file or directory`

How can I resolve it ? Knowing that, when downloading Solr, there is no such file of crawldb.

Comment: Have you actually set the SPARKLER_GIT_SOURCE_PATH environment variable that you're trying to read the path from? I think the point is that you're supposed to substitute that with the path to where you downloaded sparkler (or set the env var appropriately)

Comment: Thank you for your help, that seems to be the case.